# in beforeTextChange, value already changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a TextWatcher on an EditText.  In beforeTextChanged, I'm finding that the EditText value has already been changed.  Here's a snip of code:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
{
//      restoreValue = text.getText().toString();
  String restoreValue = s.toString();
  System.out.println ("restore |" + restoreValue + "|");
}
```

In this function the debug output shows a modified string, not the original value of the EditText.  It is the same whether I obtain the value from "text" (which is the EditText widget) or from "s".

Anyone have a possible reason for this?

Comment: A little more info: when I do a paste operation, beforeTextChanged gets called twice.  The first time, it shows that a space is being added at the end of the selected segment.  The second time is the actual paste.  The first time - inserting the space - is weird.  I need to ignore this, somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is simple.  Android is trying to be clever, figuring that your insertion is supposed to be a word, and adding a space to separate it from the other text.  Thus, first it inserts the space (possibly two spaces - one at each end of the selected area), and then it inserts the paste-buffer text.

Each of these actions causes a separate call to beforeTextChanged.  Same for onTextChanged and afterTextChanged.

So, for a paste action, you can get up to three sets of callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code it is working

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(count>0)
                Log.e("MIS",""+s.toString().substring(0,count-1));
            }
```

Comment: You have nothing but autogenerated stubs.

Comment: Sorry, that won't help either.  The problem, as I stated above, is that paste actions are causing two calls to onTextChanged, one of them with a blank insert at the right end of the paste region.